# How to package SC instrument for beta testers?

Tags: python, audio, redis, vst, supercollider

I've built a sample instrument using the following architecture:

A python script reads sample files from a Redis database stored on disk and sends OSC messages to super collider with the path and pitch of a random selection of N samples. On the SC side, the key presses form a midi interface are mapped to select and play one or more of the corresponding samples.

The prototype is functional, and I would like to release a beta for testers, however I have no clue on how to package it. One option that seems plausible is wrap it as a VST, but as far as I understand, there is no stable wrapper for SC and the safest bet would be to re-code the entire instrument into VST.

Another option, that seems more viable, would be to wrap it as a standalone instrument. Would I need to have the beta testers have SC installed, or is there a way to wrap a SC server inside an executable?

Any ideas on this issue--even if they divert from my original approach-- will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately there are lots of options for this in SuperCollider. You may want to start by reviewing [this](http://doc.sccode.org/Guides/standalones.html) article from the documentation, in which Making Standalone Applications is discussed rather thoroughly.

Alternately, there are some pre-built standalones floating around, frequently on GitHub. I frequently use [this](https://github.com/redFrik/supercolliderStandaloneRPI2) repository to package up an installation or instrument and deploy on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with VST or Supercollider, but maybe you could try something like [Docker](https://www.docker.com).  This is a container based solution which might meet your needs

You set up a Dockerfile, which lets you provide instructions to build a container with the SC Server.  Then let the person using it decide whether they want a Redis instance inside the same docker container, or if they want to use a separate [Redis Container](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would the testers need to have docker installed in their systems, or is there a way to bundle the docker server within the same app?

Comment: They would need to have docker installed in order to run an image you provide, but that's it. Everything else they need would be built inside the container.  Basically, after installing docker they would execute 'docker run your-app-name' to start the application.